# Finding line segments on the image by using ImageLines

Tags: image-processing

There is an image from [wolfram documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageLines.html)

[image]

I want to find and highlight lines on the following image

[image]

I tried:

```
img = Import["http://imgur.com/NbNwYWC.png"]

lines = ImageLines[EdgeDetect[img], MaxFeatures -> 5]

HighlightImage[img, {Red, Thick, Line /@ lines}]
```

but...

[image]

Comment: Increasing the size of the edge filter gives much better results, but I'm sure someone with more experience with image processing functions can come up with a more reliable way: `ImageLines[EdgeDetect[img, 20], MaxFeatures -> 9]`

Comment: I can only suggest one segment which is positioned almost perfectly: `HighlightImage[img, {White, Style[Line[{{361, 686}, {136, 39}}], Antialiasing -> False]}]`.

Comment: play w/ `Binarize` too: `ImageLines[EdgeDetect[Binarize[img, .2], 20], MaxFeatures -> 5]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing I did was to Binarize the image.  I tried several different variations, but ChanVeseBinarize worked the best.  I picked gray as my foreground color and black as the background.  The streets are mostly in the shadows, and I used gray on a hunch.  Later, I tried DominantColors on the image, and the 2nd and 3rd colors were two grays, so I think there is a good reason that gray works well.

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlNpX.png"]
img2=ChanVeseBinarize[img,{{Gray,Black}}]
```

[image: Binarized]

Then, run EdgeDetect on the Binarized image.  Making the range too big or too small affected the line fitting and the angles of the final lines.  (This image is omitted because I can only post 2 links.)

```
img3=EdgeDetect[img2,10]
```

Finally, run ImageLines and composite the image.

```
lines=ImageLines[img3,MaxFeatures->10];
img4=Show[img,Graphics[{Thick,White,Line/@lines}]]
```

[image: Final]

I tried several other preprocessing steps, but with my limited skills, the above worked the best.  I would think there is some combination of manipulating color and contrast at first, then binarizing the image, and finally dilating/eroding the resulting black and white image in the right way to help accent the streets.  However, I couldn't beat the above combination.